# Ensure that all samples in a batch have the same shape in pytorch dataloader

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, sliding-window

My task is to do a multi label classification on a custom dataset with pyTorch and BERT. My data contains about 1500 samples. The amount of words can vary between 1000 and 50k words. Because BERT can only handle a max sequence of 512 I am using a sliding window approach on my data. Please note that a data sample can  has several sentences.

For reference I´m working with the example notebooks [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/abhimishra91/transformers-tutorials/blob/master/transformers_multi_label_classification.ipynb) and from [huggingface](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/question_answering.ipynb).

Here is a minimal version of my script:

```
import transformers
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel, BertConfig
import pandas as pd
import torch
from torch import cuda
import math
import transformers
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel, BertConfig, AutoTokenizer
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler
device = 'cuda' if cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

MAX_LEN = 400
STRIDE = 20
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 8
VALID_BATCH_SIZE = 4
EPOCHS = 1
LEARNING_RATE = 1e-05

model_checkpoint = "bert-base-german-cased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint, local_files_only=True)
assert isinstance(tokenizer, transformers.PreTrainedTokenizerFast)

class CustomDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, dataframe, tokenizer, max_len, stride):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.data = dataframe
        self.text = dataframe.text
        self.targets = self.data.labels
        self.max_len = max_len
        self.stride = stride

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.text)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        text = str(self.text[index])
        text = " ".join(text.split())

        inputs = self.tokenizer(
            text,
            None,
            max_length=MAX_LEN,
            stride=STRIDE,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation='only_first',
            return_overflowing_tokens=True,
        )
        ids = inputs['input_ids']
        mask = inputs['attention_mask']
        token_type_ids = inputs["token_type_ids"]


        return {
            'ids': torch.tensor(ids, dtype=torch.long),
            'mask': torch.tensor(mask, dtype=torch.long),
            'token_type_ids': torch.tensor(token_type_ids, dtype=torch.long),
            'targets': torch.tensor(self.targets[index], dtype=torch.float)
        }
```

I think the sliding window is working because if I run `[len(x) for x in inputs["input_ids"]]` I get a list of input_ids for my paragraph/text.

```
# Creating the dataset and dataloader for the neural network
train_size = 0.8
train_dataset=training_frame.sample(frac=train_size,random_state=200)
test_dataset=training_frame.drop(train_dataset.index).reset_index(drop=True)
train_dataset = train_dataset.reset_index(drop=True)

print("FULL Dataset: {}".format(training_frame.shape))
print("TRAIN Dataset: {}".format(train_dataset.shape))
print("TEST Dataset: {}".format(test_dataset.shape))


training_set = CustomDataset(train_dataset, tokenizer, MAX_LEN, STRIDE)
testing_set = CustomDataset(test_dataset, tokenizer, MAX_LEN, STRIDE)

train_params = {'batch_size': TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE,
                'shuffle': False,
                'num_workers': 0
                }

test_params = {'batch_size': VALID_BATCH_SIZE,
                'shuffle': True,
                'num_workers': 0
                }

training_loader = DataLoader(training_set, **train_params)
testing_loader = DataLoader(testing_set, **test_params)
```

Until here the script is running without any error, but if I try to iterate over `training_set` like here:

```
train_iter = iter(training_loader)
print(type(train_iter))
text, labels = train_iter.next()
print(text.size())
print(labels.size())
```

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: invalid argument 0: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 0. Got 133 and 75 in dimension 1 at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556653215914/work/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensor.cpp:711

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60154328/pytorch-lstm-runtimeerror-invalid-argument-0-sizes-of-tensors-must-match-exce) André mentions that the loaded batches have different shapes and that´s how this error occures. He suggests to set the `batch_size = 1`. However I want to use the defined the `batch_size` defined in my script.

I think the sliding window causes the error because the list of `input_ids` can vary per sample in my batchsamples because the total length of the text can be different.
How can I ensure that my data fed to the network has always the same shape?

Comment: Did you try passing `drop_last=True` as a parameter to the `DataLoader`s?

Comment: @MustafaAydın I think this is not a valid parameter for the [tokenizer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__)

Comment: I meant passing here: `training_loader = DataLoader(training_set, **train_params, drop_last=True)`

Comment: my bad sorry, I just tried it but the error stays the same.

Comment: Try to move tokenization( `tokenizer`) out of `__get_item()`

Comment: Also, it's preferable to use `tokenizer.batch_encode_plus`

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa Thanks for your comment. But can you please explain why I should move the tokenizer out of the get_item() function?

Comment: It's possible that tokenizer is not called on a whole batch, but independently on a individual sample, thus creating varied length tensors.